# How to prevent browser ding sound with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I'm using jwerty plugin to handle keyboard events and I created a combination: "alt+a".

It's working well, event firing, but windows's ding! Sound is coming. It's so annoying.

How can I prevent it?

Here is the link, hear it yourself : http://jsfiddle.net/YShy9/3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because there is no access key defined for Alt-A.  A quick solution is to add something like this to your HTML:

```
<div accesskey="a"></div>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aTQ3M/).

Comment: Awesome, learn something new everyday :) Heres the answer applied to his fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/YShy9/5/

Comment: Thanks!  I like your fiddle better :)

Comment: meh you'rs is more clear and concise, I just did it real quick to see if itd work. Again nice catch!